# Asp.net webform error while building

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have to work on old asp.net website project and after compiling the source code i get following error

> Error  378 Cannot implicitly convert type 'PagerControl.LinkType [c:\Site1\images\en\UserControls\PagerControl.ascx.cs(174)]' to 'PagerControl.LinkType [c:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\9aba16fa\a35916ab\App_Web_2ndhi1qd.dll]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)  C:\Site1\images\en\UserControls\Featured-Video.ascx 33

This has a user control for Pager which works fine for ENglish Version for Arabic version it generates error while both codes are same with different class name

I am able to run this project without any issue paging working fine of related pages so not sure why this error is being generated

```
Code of User control 

<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PagerControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="AR_PagerControlArabic" %>

<ul runat="server" id="pnlPager"  class="pagination" />
```

**Codebehind**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class AR_PagerControlArabic : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when the pager linkbutton is clicked.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler PagerControl_PageIndexChanged;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /// since the pagination link buttons are dynamic controls we need to recreate them after postback
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            if (PageMode == LinkType.LinkButton)
            {
                CreateLinkButtonPagination();
            }
        }
    }

    #region Public Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the offset of the pagination number
    /// </summary>
    public int IndexDisplayOffset
    {
        get { return ViewState["IndexDisplayOffset"] == null ? 1 : (int)ViewState["IndexDisplayOffset"]; }
        set { ViewState["IndexDisplayOffset"] = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the mode of pagination buttons to render
    /// </summary>
    public LinkType PageMode
    {
        get { return ViewState["PageMode"] == null ? LinkType.HyperLink : (LinkType)ViewState["PageMode"]; }
        set { ViewState["PageMode"] = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the total number of rows in the datasource
    /// </summary>
    public int TotalItems
    {
        get { return ViewState["TotalItems"] == null ? 0 : (int)ViewState["TotalItems"]; }
        set { ViewState["TotalItems"] = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The number of items per page. The maximum number of pages is calculated by 
    /// dividing the number of items by items_per_page (rounded up, minimum 1). Default: 10
    /// </summary>
    public int PageSize
    {
        get { return ViewState["PageSize"] == null ? 10 : (int)ViewState["PageSize"]; }
        set { ViewState["PageSize"] = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The page that is selected when the pagination is initialized. Default: 0
    /// </summary>
    public int CurrentPageIndex //made the paginator with start index from 0 and later changed to 1 - with this simple patch ;)
    {
        get { return _CurrentPageIndex + 1; }
        set { _CurrentPageIndex = value - 1; }
    }
    private int _CurrentPageIndex
    {
        get { return ViewState["CurrentPageIndex"] == null ? 0 : (int)ViewState["CurrentPageIndex"]; }
        set { ViewState["CurrentPageIndex"] = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Maximum number of pagination links that are visible. Set to 0 to display a
    /// simple "Previous/Next"-Navigation. Default: 10
    /// </summary>
    public int DisplayEntriesCount
    {
        get { return ViewState["DisplayEntriesCount"] == null ? 10 : (int)ViewState["DisplayEntriesCount"]; }
        set { ViewState["DisplayEntriesCount"] = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// If this number is set to 1, links to the first and the last page are always shown
    /// , independent of the current position and the visibility constraints set by num_display_entries
    /// . You can set it to bigger numbers to show more links. Default is 2
    /// </summary>
    public int EdgeEntriesCount
    {
        get { return ViewState["EdgeEntriesCount"] == null ? 2 : (int)ViewState["EdgeEntriesCount"]; }
        set { ViewState["EdgeEntriesCount"] = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Link target of the pagination links when the PageMode = HyperLink. Default: ?p=
    /// Priority goes for TargetLinkFormatString
    /// </summary>
    public string TargetLink
    {
        get { return ViewState["TargetLink"] == null ? "?p=" : ViewState["TargetLink"].ToString(); }
        set { ViewState["TargetLink"] = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// SEO friendly link target of the pagination links when the PageMode = HyperLink. Default is empty
    /// </summary>
    public string TargetLinkFormatString
    {
        get { return ViewState["TargetLinkFormat"] == null ? string.Empty : ViewState["TargetLinkFormat"].ToString(); }
        set { ViewState["TargetLinkFormat"] = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Text for the "Previous"-link that decreases the current page number by 1. 
    /// Leave blank to hide the link. Default: « prev
    /// </summary>
    public string PreviousPageText
    {
        //get { return ViewState["PreviousPageText"] == null ? "&laquo; prev" : ViewState["PreviousPageText"].ToString(); }
       // get { return ViewState["PreviousPageText"] == null ? " &laquo; " : ViewState["PreviousPageText"].ToString(); }
        get { return ViewState["PreviousPageText"] == null ? " &lt; " : ViewState["PreviousPageText"].ToString(); }
        set { ViewState["PreviousPageText"] = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Text for the "Next"-link that increases the current page number by 1. 
    /// Leave blank to hide the link. Default: next »
    /// </summary>
    public string NextPageText
    {
        //get { return ViewState["NextPageText"] == null ? "next &raquo;" : ViewState["NextPageText"].ToString(); }
        //get { return ViewState["NextPageText"] == null ? " &raquo; " : ViewState["NextPageText"].ToString(); }
        get { return ViewState["NextPageText"] == null ? " &gt; " : ViewState["NextPageText"].ToString(); }
        set { ViewState["NextPageText"] = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When there is a gap between the numbers created by EdgeEntriesCount and the displayed number interval
    /// , this text will be inserted into the gap (inside a Label/span tag).
    /// </summary>
    public string EllipseText
    {
        get { return ViewState["EllipseText"] == null ? "..." : ViewState["EllipseText"].ToString(); }
        set { ViewState["EllipseText"] = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or set the css class name for the pagination div. Default: 'pagination'
    /// </summary>
    public string CssClass
    {
        get { return pnlPager.Attributes["class"]; }
        set { pnlPager.Attributes["class"] = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region enums
    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies the types of buttons to render
    /// </summary>
    public enum LinkType
    {
        HyperLink, LinkButton
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Functions
    /// <summary>
    /// Bind the data to a control and generate the pagination.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bindControl">Type of DataList, Repeater, DataGrid or GridView</param>
    /// <param name="data">The datatable to bind</param>
    public void BindDataWithPaging(Control bindControl, DataTable data)
    {
        DataView dv = data.DefaultView;

        //saving the total items count in Viewstate for later use
        TotalItems = data.Rows.Count;

        PagedDataSource dsP = new PagedDataSource();
        dsP.AllowPaging = true;
        dsP.PageSize = PageSize;
        dsP.DataSource = dv;

        //current page index shld be set before calling this function - especially in the case of HyperLinks        
        //if the current pagfe index is greater than the number of pages availanble. make the current page index as the last page
        if (_CurrentPageIndex > dsP.PageCount - 1)
            _CurrentPageIndex = dsP.PageCount - 1;
        else if (_CurrentPageIndex < 0)
            _CurrentPageIndex = 0;
        dsP.CurrentPageIndex = _CurrentPageIndex;

        //Binding data to the controls
        if (bindControl is DataList)
            ((DataList)bindControl).DataSource = dsP;
        else if (bindControl is Repeater)
            ((Repeater)bindControl).DataSource = dsP;
        else if (bindControl is DataGrid)
            ((DataGrid)bindControl).DataSource = dsP;
        else if (bindControl is GridView)
            ((GridView)bindControl).DataSource = dsP;

        bindControl.DataBind();

        CreatePagination();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create the pagination as per the TotalItems available and the PageSize
    /// Call this function directly after setting TotalItems and PagSize if you want to generate the pagination without binding data to a specific control
    /// </summary>
    public void CreatePagination()
    {
        if (TotalPages() > 1)
        {
            this.Visible = true;
            if (PageMode == LinkType.HyperLink)
                CreateHyperLinkPagination();
            else
                CreateLinkButtonPagination();
        }
        else
        {
            this.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Function to calculate the total number of pages depending on TotalItems and PageSize
    /// </summary>
    public int TotalPages()
    {
        return int.Parse(Math.Ceiling(decimal.Parse(TotalItems.ToString())
            / decimal.Parse(PageSize.ToString())).ToString());
    }

    #endregion

    #region CreateHyperLinkPagination
    //create the pagination as Hyperlinks
    private void CreateHyperLinkPagination()
    {
        string ellipses = "<li class=\"plain\">" + EllipseText + " </li>";

        //this string builder will hold the pagination string and later we will add this to a div 
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        //finidng the central postion of display entries. The current page will be shown in the center
        int ne_half = int.Parse(Math.Ceiling(decimal.Parse(DisplayEntriesCount.ToString()) / 2).ToString());

        //retrieving the number of pages
        int np = TotalPages();

        int upper_limit = np - DisplayEntriesCount;

        //finding the start position
        int start = _CurrentPageIndex > ne_half ? Math.Max(Math.Min(_CurrentPageIndex - ne_half, upper_limit), 0) : 0;

        //finding the end position
        int end = _CurrentPageIndex > ne_half ? Math.Min(_CurrentPageIndex + ne_half, np) : Math.Min(DisplayEntriesCount, np);

        // Begin by creating the 'Previous' Link 
        if (PreviousPageText.Length > 0)
        {
            sb.Append(CreateLink(_CurrentPageIndex - 1, PreviousPageText, _CurrentPageIndex == 0 ? "disabled" : "")).Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
        }

        // Generate begining edge entries - The first EdgeEntriesCount of page links will be generated 
        if (start > 0 && EdgeEntriesCount > 0)
        {
            //till where the edge entries created
            int edgeEnd = Math.Min(EdgeEntriesCount, start);
            for (int i = 0; i < edgeEnd; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(CreateLink(i, (i + 1).ToString(), "")).Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
            }
            //if there is a gap between edge entries and start,, ellipse text will be shown bw them
            if (EdgeEntriesCount < start && EllipseText.Length > 0)
            {
                sb.Append(ellipses).Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }

        // Generate interval links - the pagination links based on DisplayEntriesCount will generated here
        //links will be printed from the calculated start and end values
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(CreateLink(i, (i + 1).ToString(), "")).Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
        }

        // Generate ending edge entries - The final EdgeEntriesCount of page links will be generated 
        if (end < np && EdgeEntriesCount > 0)
        {
            //if there is a gap between end link and edge entries the EllipseText will be shown
            if (np - EdgeEntriesCount > end && EllipseText.Length > 0)
            {
                sb.Append(ellipses).Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
            }

            //from where the edge entries should start
            int begin = Math.Max(np - EdgeEntriesCount, end);
            for (int i = begin; i < np; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(CreateLink(i, (i + 1).ToString(), "")).Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }

        // Finish the pagination with 'Next' Link
        if (NextPageText.Length > 0)
        {
            sb.Append(CreateLink(_CurrentPageIndex + 1, NextPageText, _CurrentPageIndex == end - 1 ? "disabled" : "")).Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
        }

        pnlPager.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
    }

    // Helper function for generating a single link (or a span tag if it's the current page)
    string CreateLink(int pageNumber, string displayText, string className)
    {
        string link = "";
        //retrive total number of pages available
        int np = TotalPages();

        //if the passed value is < 0 set it as zero.. else if the passed value is greater than total pages set it as total pages - 1
        pageNumber = pageNumber < 0 ? 0 : (pageNumber < np ? pageNumber : np - 1);

        //if its the current page make it a span
        if (pageNumber == _CurrentPageIndex)
        {
            //if no class name is passed, set current as class name
            link = string.Format("<li class='{0}'>{1}</li>"
                , className.Length > 0 ? className : "current"
                , displayText);
        }
        else //make it as a link
        {
            if (TargetLinkFormatString.Length > 0) //if SEO friendly page target is specified - use it
            {
                link = string.Format(TargetLinkFormatString, pageNumber + IndexDisplayOffset);
                link = string.Format("<li><a href='{0}'>{1}</a></li>  ", link, displayText);
            }
            else
                link = string.Format("<li><a href='{0}{1}'>{2}</a></li> ", TargetLink, pageNumber + IndexDisplayOffset, displayText);

        }

        return link;
    }
    #endregion

    #region CreateLinkButtonPagination

    //create the pagination as LinkButtons
    private void CreateLinkButtonPagination()
    {
        pnlPager.Controls.Clear();

        //finidng the central postion of display entries. The current page will be shown in the center
        int ne_half = int.Parse(Math.Ceiling(decimal.Parse(DisplayEntriesCount.ToString()) / 2).ToString());

        //retrieving the number of pages
        int np = TotalPages();

        int upper_limit = np - DisplayEntriesCount;

        //finding the start position of the main pager strip
        int start = _CurrentPageIndex > ne_half ? Math.Max(Math.Min(_CurrentPageIndex - ne_half, upper_limit), 0) : 0;

        //finding the end position of the main pager strip
        int end = _CurrentPageIndex > ne_half ? Math.Min(_CurrentPageIndex + ne_half, np) : Math.Min(DisplayEntriesCount, np);

        // Begin by creating the 'Previous' Link 
        if (PreviousPageText.Length > 0)
            CreateButton(_CurrentPageIndex - 1, PreviousPageText, _CurrentPageIndex == 0 ? "disabled" : "");

        // Generate begining edge entries - The first EdgeEntriesCount of page links will be generated 
        if (start > 0 && EdgeEntriesCount > 0)
        {
            //till where the edge entries created
            int edgeEnd = Math.Min(EdgeEntriesCount, start);
            for (int i = 0; i < edgeEnd; i++)
            {
                CreateButton(i, (i + 1).ToString(), "");
            }
            //if there is a gap between edge entries and start,, ellipse text will be shown bw them
            if (EdgeEntriesCount < start && EllipseText.Length > 0)
            {
                CreateLabel(EllipseText, "plain");
            }
        }

        // Generate interval links - the pagination links based on DisplayEntriesCount will generated here
        //links will be printed from the calculated start and end values
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        {
            CreateButton(i, (i + 1).ToString(), "");
        }

        // Generate ending edge entries - The final EdgeEntriesCount of page links will be generated 
        if (end < np && EdgeEntriesCount > 0)
        {
            //if there is a gap between end link and edge entries the EllipseText will be shown
            if (np - EdgeEntriesCount > end && EllipseText.Length > 0)
            {
                CreateLabel(EllipseText, "plain");
            }

            //from where the edge entries should start
            int begin = Math.Max(np - EdgeEntriesCount, end);
            for (int i = begin; i < np; i++)
            {
                CreateButton(i, (i + 1).ToString(), "");
            }
        }

        // Finish the pagination with 'Next' Link
        if (NextPageText.Length > 0)
            CreateButton(_CurrentPageIndex + 1, NextPageText, _CurrentPageIndex == end - 1 ? "disabled" : "");

    }

    private void CreateButton(int pageNumber, string displayText, string className)
    {
        //retrive total number of pages available
        int np = TotalPages();

        //if the passed value is < 0 set it as zero.. else if the passed value is greater than total pages set it as total pages - 1
        pageNumber = pageNumber < 0 ? 0 : (pageNumber < np ? pageNumber : np - 1);

        //if its the current page make it a Label
        if (pageNumber == _CurrentPageIndex)
        {
            //if no class name is passed, set current as class name
            CreateLabel(displayText, className.Length > 0 ? className : "current");
        }
        else //make it as a linkbutton
        {
            CreateLinkButton(displayText, pageNumber);
        }
    }

    private void CreateLinkButton(string title, int index)
    {
        Literal litNewLine = new Literal();
        litNewLine.Text = System.Environment.NewLine;
        pnlPager.Controls.Add(litNewLine);

        LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();

        if (title == PreviousPageText)
            lnk.ID = "-1";
        else if (title == NextPageText)
            lnk.ID = TotalItems.ToString();
        else
            lnk.ID = index.ToString();

        lnk.Text = title;
        lnk.CommandArgument = index.ToString();
        lnk.Click += new EventHandler(lnkPager_Click);
        HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        li.Controls.Add(lnk);

        pnlPager.Controls.Add(li);
    }

    private void CreateLabel(string title, string cssClass)
    {
        Literal litNewLine = new Literal();
        litNewLine.Text = System.Environment.NewLine;
        pnlPager.Controls.Add(litNewLine);

        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.ID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        lbl.Text = title;
        HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        li.Attributes.Add("class", cssClass);
        li.Controls.Add(lbl);

        pnlPager.Controls.Add(li);
    }

    protected void lnkPager_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Page index changed function
    {
        LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)sender;
        _CurrentPageIndex = int.Parse(lnk.CommandArgument);

        if (PagerControl_PageIndexChanged != null)
            PagerControl_PageIndexChanged(this, e);

    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Does Clean Solution then Build Solution help?

Comment: @mjwills, I am doing that now to see if does publish to folder without any issue

Comment: @mjwills, Site was published successfully file:///C:/Published_Site1

Comment: Website was always working but when try to Build it in VS 2013 it gives me this error not sure why? i even deleted all the temp files but error keeps coming back but has no impact when i run the website it functions without any issue

Comment: Is this a Web Site template or a Web Application Project template? Web Site templates are known for this type of error. I strongly suggest you switch to the WAP template especially if using user controls.

Comment: Have you looked at Featured-Video.ascx? not sure why but it's mentioned in the error. a cast might be missing, something like `(LinkType)ViewState["PageMode"];` above.

Comment: I resolved the issue after carefully looking at it i noticed that some user control files where also copied to in image folder which was creating conflict. Not sure how that happened anyways everything is working and pre-compiled also without any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was solved as i noticed the some of the USer Control files where accidentally copied into image folder also resulting in duplicate class which was creating this problem, after removing these duplicate files from image folder issue is resolved.